# box-shadow disappears when zoomed too far out

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

I want my first column to freeze when the user scrolls horizontally. Originally, the borders were not staying when I scrolled so I looked around, and most places recommended using "box-shadow".

However, when I zoom out enough (say 75% or less) the box-shadow disappears entirely when scrolling. I'm sure this is due to the width of my box-shadow only being 1px, but I can't exactly make that thicker as it "leaks" out from the borders and makes the general layout of the table look slightly off.

```
    <TDHeader
      color={
        (level.level + zebraStripOffset) % 2 === 0
          ? "rgba(242, 242, 242, 1)"
          : "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
      }
      shadow={
        "1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(147, 147, 147, 1), -0.5px 0px 0px 0px rgba(147, 147, 147, 1)"
      }
      className="bold"
      rowSpan={2}
      hideLeft={true}
      borderBottom={isLastRow}
    >
      {level.level}
    </TDHeader>
```

When scrolled at 100% zoom, everything looks dandy:
[image: shadow-with-scroll]

However, in this case, if I even zoom out to 90%, the box-shadow disappears on scroll:
[image]

If I change the horizontal offset to 1.5, things like fine:
 [image]

But, when I zoom back out to 100%, you see that the borders look "offset" as the shadow leaks out to the right a little.
[image]

So, what might my best plan of action be here?